# ScintillaNET not showing folding for method blocks

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-controls, folding, scintillanet

I'm using the **[ScinctillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/issues/29)** editor, and, the problem I have is that it does not show the "[+]" and the "[-] folding symbols for methods, at least for the Vb.Net lexer as shown in this image:

( notice the missing symbol in line number **6** and **32** )
[image]

I'm not sure I'f its a design issue in the wrapper by the author, or its my fault, this is the style that I'm building, written in Vb.Net:

```
Public Shared Sub SetVbNetStyle(ByVal editor As Scintilla)

    Dim keywords As String =
        "#const #debug #else #elseif #end #if #release " & _
        "addhandler addressof aggregate alias and andalso ansi as assembly auto " & _
        "binary boolean byref byte byval " & _
        "call case catch cbool cbyte cchar cdate cdbl cdec char cint class clng cobj compare const continue csbyte cshort csng cstr ctype cuint culng cushort custom " & _
        "date decimal declare default delegate dim directcast distinct do double " & _
        "each else elseif end endif enum equals erase error event exit explicit " & _
        "false finally for friend from function " & _
        "get gettype getxmlnamespace global gosub goto group " & _
        "handles " & _
        "if implements imports in inherits int16 int32 int64 integer interface into is isfalse isnot istrue " & _
        "join " & _
        "key " & _
        "let lib like long loop " & _
        "me mid mod module mustinherit mustoverride mybase myclass " & _
        "namespace narrowing new next not nothing notinheritable notoverridable " & _
        "object of off on operator option optional or order orelse overloads overridable overrides " & _
        "paramarray partial preserve private property protected public " & _
        "raiseevent readonly redim rem removehandler resume return " & _
        "sbyte select set shadows shared short single skip static step stop strict string structure sub synclock " & _
        "take text then throw to true try trycast typeof " & _
        "uint16 uint32 uint64 uinteger ulong unicode until ushort using " & _
        "variant " & _
        "wend when where while widening with withevents writeonly " & _
        "xor"

    ' Reset the styles.
    editor.StyleResetDefault()
    editor.StyleClearAll()
    ' editor.Styles(Style.[Default]).Font = "Consolas"
    ' editor.Styles(Style.[Default]).Size = 10

    ' Set the Vb.Net lexer.
    editor.Lexer = Lexer.Vb

    ' Set folding properties.
    editor.SetProperty("tab.timmy.whinge.level", "1")
    editor.SetProperty("fold", "1")

    ' Set the margin for fold markers.
    With editor
        .Margins(2).Type = MarginType.Symbol
        .Margins(2).Mask = Marker.MaskFolders
        .Margins(2).Sensitive = True
        .Margins(2).Width = 20
    End With

    ' Reset folder markers.
    For i As Integer = Marker.FolderEnd To Marker.FolderOpen
        editor.Markers(i).SetForeColor(SystemColors.ControlLightLight)
        editor.Markers(i).SetBackColor(SystemColors.ControlDark)
    Next

    ' Set the style of the folder markers.
    With editor
        .Markers(Marker.Folder).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.BoxPlus
        .Markers(Marker.Folder).SetBackColor(SystemColors.ControlText)
        .Markers(Marker.FolderOpen).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.BoxMinus
        .Markers(Marker.FolderEnd).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.BoxPlusConnected
        .Markers(Marker.FolderEnd).SetBackColor(SystemColors.ControlText)
        .Markers(Marker.FolderMidTail).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.TCorner
        .Markers(Marker.FolderOpenMid).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.BoxMinusConnected
        .Markers(Marker.FolderSub).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.VLine
        .Markers(Marker.FolderTail).Symbol = MarkerSymbol.LCorner
    End With

    ' Enable automatic folding
    editor.AutomaticFold = (AutomaticFold.Show Or AutomaticFold.Click Or AutomaticFold.Change)

    ' Disable whitespaces visibility.
    editor.ViewWhitespace = WhitespaceMode.Invisible

    ' Set the style of the Vb.Net language.
    With editor
        .Styles(Style.Default).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Comment).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Comment).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 87, 159, 56)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Comment).Italic = False
        .Styles(Style.Vb.CommentBlock).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.CommentBlock).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(127, 127, 127)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.CommentBlock).Italic = True
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Default).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Default).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.HexNumber).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.HexNumber).Bold = True
        .Styles(Style.Vb.HexNumber).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 181, 206, 168)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Identifier).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Identifier).ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword).Bold = False
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 139, 214)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword2).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword2).Bold = False
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword2).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 139, 214)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword3).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword3).Bold = False
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword3).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 139, 214)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword4).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword4).Bold = False
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Keyword4).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 139, 214)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Number).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Number).Bold = True
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Number).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 181, 206, 168)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Operator).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Operator).Bold = True
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Operator).ForeColor = Color.Silver
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Preprocessor).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.Preprocessor).ForeColor = Color.MediumOrchid
        .Styles(Style.Vb.String).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.String).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 214, 157, 133)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.StringEol).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30)
        .Styles(Style.Vb.StringEol).FillLine = True
        .Styles(Style.Vb.StringEol).ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
    End With

    ' Set the Vb.Net keywords.
    editor.SetKeywords(1, keywords)


End Sub
```

Comment: For the user who tried to untag the C# tag, please remember that .Net invovles various supported languages and OPs are allowed to ask for a solution in those languages, so I ask for whatever a solution in Vb.Net or C# no matter, because I can accept one of both, also, if someone will look to ScintillaNET source-code to inspect the cause of this issue then it involves C# knowledges. Thanks.

Comment: I dug a little into this project. It maybe in the `folding.cs` class, not sure though. I will dig more later...  https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Branches/4.0/ScintillaNET/Folding.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior appears to be a "feature" in native Scintilla, not just the .NET wrapper.  It can also be seen in the SciTE editor.  I found this VB-folding-related [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/1558/), which was reclassified as a feature request.  It was submitted in 2013, regarding VB6, but appears to be applicable.  It states that the VB folder is based on *indentation*, not syntax.

Using your provided style, I was able to replicate your described issue. Once at least one space indentation was present on each nested line, even the blank lines, the folding appeared as expected.